# Stationary powerfull PC stream

Tags: laptop, desktop-computer

I'm wondering would it be possible to set up powerful PC somewhere at home and access and use it via laptop? Would a Teamviewer or some analog be able to handle it so there is almost no noticeable latency while using it in the same network?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the stream? Any kind of streaming will in one way or another degrade performance. If you plan to stream video, compression of the video stream will happen, but will make it watchable, although in a lower quality. If you plan to do gaming, look into a ready made game streaming service, such as steam or nvidia shield. There still will be some lag, but given that it is optimized for games, most games will feel smooth and only in certain conditions will you experience the lag.

Comment: "powerful" means different things to different people. What is the purpose? For computations (like compiling, transcoding etc) and storage, yes you can do this. For video and gaming, no, local GPU is essential.

Comment: My primary usage would be playing games or using CAD like software